# How to build and deploy Macchina.io on Windows

Tags: poco, poco-libraries

Macchina uses POCO and OpenSSL .I was able to build all the dlls in POCO but not able to understand how to deploy it.
[macchina.io website](http://macchina.io/docs/)

Answer (score 1):

Although it is planned and all code is portable, there is currently no support for building macchina.io on Windows, mainly because [GYP is needed](https://code.google.com/p/v8-wiki/wiki/BuildingWithGYP) for V8 build and only macchina.io platform has Visual Studio projects available; for the rest, the work of generating VS projects has not been done yet. If you feel inclined, [Poco::ProGen](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/tree/develop/ProGen) is the tool used in Poco for that purpose.

Comment: So its better I do it on Linux?

Comment: Yes, Linux and OSX build and run out of the box, see [README.md](https://github.com/macchina-io/macchina.io/blob/develop/README.md)